# Mutual thread exclusion in a JAVA method

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I need to provide mutual access to a method of a class, so one thread at time can execute the code inside the method.
I have tried the solution below but I cannot understand why every time the value of the variable 'locked' is false.

```
public class MyCommand extends BaseCommand {
  private static boolean locked=false;

  @Override
  public  boolean execute() throws Exception {
    synchronized(MyCommand.class){
        while (locked){
            wait();
        }
        locked=true;

         //some code with a breakpoint/long blocking operations

        locked=false;
        notifyAll();
        return true;
  }
}
```

I have placed a breakpoint in the while statement at the beginning and the value of the variable locked is always false and I cannot understand why.
The second breakpoint is in the body of the method and I use it in order to block the execution of the first thread and see the the value of the variable locked changed in the second thread, but unfortunately it is not happening.
Therefore, as end results all the threads are able to execute this method without any thread safeness.
Does anybody have an idea on how I can provide exclusive access to this method one thread per time?

Comment: this.class is not a valid expression. Please fix.

Comment: If there's no shared mutable data then your Command is perfectly thread safe.  How to do that?  Don't modify state of reference parameters; don't create any mutable class member variables.  Why can't you just add the synchronized keyword?

Comment: You don't need the `locked` static field. `syncronized(MyCommand.class)` is sufficient.

Comment: What is the reason to have both, a synchronized block and a locking variable? Java's monitors are mutexes.

Comment: Anyway I would use a ReentrantLock instead, it's much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only one thread is inside the synchronized block at a time, right?
You stop your thread at the beginning of the block, and check the value of `locked`. Well, if your thread is inside the block, that means that no other thread is. And if no other thread is inside, then `locked` has to to be false, that's the whole point. Why does it surprise you?

You don't need the `while(locked) wait()` loop by the way (or the whole `locked` thing for that matter) exactly for the reason described above - the whole "locking" is achieved by having the `synchronized` lock around your code.

Comment: thanks Dima, another question for you I have noticed that I achieve the mutual exclusion with the block synchronized(MyClass.class){} inside the method, but I cannot understand why when I remove the block and I put synchronized on the method declaration (public synchronized boolean execute()) things stops to work, do you know why?

Comment: @daniele No, I don't know why ... But I might be able to think of something if you care to get into a little more details about what are "things", how you expect them to "work", and what exactly happens when they "stop to work" :)

Comment: in the case that I have the block synchronized defined explicitly inside the method (synchronized(MyClass.class){ int a=1;} ) if I add a breakpoint at the line of the instruction int a=1; doesn't matter how many thread I start, the breakpoint will interrupt one one thread because the execution of the block is mutual exclusive (and it is what I expected.)

Comment: while if I remove the synchronized block and have a method like: public boolean synchronized execute(){int a=1;} and I place the breakpoint again at the line int a=1; the breakpoint will interrupt all the threads, which means that the method is not executed in a mutual exclusive way, and I cannot understand what the difference is. Because, in this case I expect the same behavior described in the comment above

Answer (score 1):

The value is always false because only one thread at a time is executing the synchronized block so... when the first thread finished the variable is false again... then, the next thread reads false.

I prefer in this scenarios to use ReentrantLock, something like:

```
protected final ReentrantLock myLock= new ReentrantLock();

...

try {
        //wait until i have the lock
        this.myLock.lock();

        //do some stuff


    } finally {
        //release the lock
        this.myLock.unlock();
    }
```

And in this article you could see the big difference in performance between synch section and ReentrantLock:
http://lycog.com/concurency/performance-reentrantlock-synchronized/

Comment: Performance does not validate the usage of ReentrantLock.  Synchronized is an intrinsic construct which can be optimized more effectively then ReentrantLock. Additionally, the throughput of synchronized has increased dramatically since Java 5, compared to ReentrantLock, and should be expected to become faster still. Finally, using a ReentrantLock requires try/finally blocks which make the code look awful, verbose, and results in boilerplate code.